# Query to tell me how many times a digit appears in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find out how many times each digit appears in a column. I have a database that stores pin numbers for parents that check their kids in and out of a preschool.

The pin numbers are stored in a `CHAR(4)` column; but they are all numeric.

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(pin) AS Count 
FROM adult 
WHERE pin LIKE '%2%';
```

Which returns these results:

```
+-------+
| Count |
+-------+
|   182 |
+-------+
```

But that only tells me how many records have a '2', not how many times it occurs (since a record could have more than 1 '2'. It's also a very manual process to go through each digit 0-9.

I'd like something that would look more like:

```
+-----+-----+
|Value|Count|
+-----+-----+
|    0|  204|
|    1|  200|
|    2|  182|
.           .
.           .
.           .
|    9|  203|
+-----+-----+
```

This is beyond my knowledge of SQL. Your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()`:

```
select substr(t.pin, n.pos, 1) as chr, count(*)
from adult t cross join
     (select 1 as pos union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n
group by substr(t.pin, n.pos, 1) 
order by chr;
```

This extracts each character in the `pin` and aggregates by the character.  The `from` clause is equivalent to:

```
from ((select substr(col, 1, 1) from adult union all
      (select substr(col, 2, 1) from adult union all
      (select substr(col, 3, 1) from adult union all
      (select substr(col, 4, 1) from adult
     ) t
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this; Expression just looks at the length of the string after replacing your value and then you `SUM` all rows to have a total / column.

```
SELECT
    1 AS Value
    ,SUM(LENGTH(pin) - LENGTH(replace(pin, '1',''))) AS Count
FROM <your_table>
UNION
SELECT
    2 AS Value
    ,SUM(LENGTH(pin) - LENGTH(replace(pin, '2',''))) AS Count
FROM <your_table>
UNION
SELECT
    3 AS Value
    ,SUM(LENGTH(pin) - LENGTH(replace(pin, '3',''))) AS Count
FROM <your_table>
....
.... and so on
```

Or you can use a variable where you store the value and iterate values from 0 to 9